# Siteground server attacked with malware

Tags: wordpress

I am just worried about malware that keeps coming in my website after cleaning couple of times. I have more than 13 websites hosting on siteground server and all websites infected with malware. I am not sure sucuri or wordfence will prevent my website attacking because both plugins already activated on the websites but still all my websites have dozens of malware infected files and each files has different weirdest names and containing with codes like 
$_i2rmt = basename/*qo*/(/*0ubcr*/trim/*pgi6*/(/*aq7l9*/preg_replace/*i5*/(/*jmy1r*/rawurldecode/*9*/

Can someone help me how to secure server and websites to prevent further malware attack.

thanks

Comment: This question is overly broad and does not indicate an effort to find your own solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Genuinely?

Make sure you have backups, check what condition those are in, nuke the servers and start over. Something is well and truly compromised and you need a clean install, hardening and new passwords and security:

Make sure that the server has up to date software.

Remove all software you don't need.

Create new databases without using the wp_ prefix

Don't use admin as an account name for wordpress, disable root log on to the server

Use fail2ban on the server to ensure that failed log in attempts mean they can't then try new ones

I don't think it is your wordpress security, as such, that is the problem. More likely the server being compromised and/or an SQL injection.